# How to embed cost of action in deep reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-belief-networks

Suppose you are training RL DQN model for lunar lander with finite fuel amount. Hence in addition to "usual" reward derived from the lunar module position there are different costs in fuel for each action.

What is the "correct" way to solve it?

Shall I subtract the fuel cost from the reward or shall I introduce additional state variable (eg fuel left)? Or is there another method?

My reservations - I feel it won't be easy for the deep learning part to figure out relationship between fuel cost/diminished reward and catastrophic agent failure when fuel is zero.

Comment: Sure, you can add fuel cost to to the objective function, so that the agent will try to minimize both duration and cost. Or you may choose one or the other, if they are related.

Comment: I added to the question - I need to see how RNN part of DQN would clearly learn that fuel is a critical resource. So I am not asking can I do this or that but rather what is scientifically suitable for the model to learn

Comment: "Shall I subtract the fuel cost from the reward" this is what @user2974951 is suggesting. "I feel it won't be easy for the deep learning part to figure out relationship between fuel cost/diminished reward and catastrophic agent failure when fuel is zero." - What makes you say this? Presumably, every time fuel goes to zero, the result is catastrophic failure, which should have a very negative reward, and so the q network will learn to predict low values for actions leading to this?

Comment: I am going to experiment of course. but would still be open to other suggestions. my "reservations" are based on the fact that coordinates and fuel are rather parts of state than reward. so subtracting from reward will lose its intuitive advantage. on other hand - if i put it in as a state variable - how can i make it _more_ obvious to the agent that it is important to stay positive. again would like more "intuitive" approach. anyway i should read "on-policy" publications probably before asking this question